# CSS convert percent to pixels

Tags: javascript, css

I have "div" element with specified width and height expressed in percents in CSS.
I would like to get by JS script its width and height expressed in pixels. It's even possible?

Comment: I want to get parent height in px and use this value to generate rest of my page

Comment: I know what you want, _what have you tried_?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
el.clientHeight;
el.clientWidth;
```

(`el`is a reference to the element)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/akrjM/89/)

Note those properties were first introduced in the MS IE DHTML object model. More recently they were standardized in [CSSOM View Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-cssom-view-20080222/), W3C Working Draft 22 February 2008.

Those properties were widely supported. However, it's possible than an old non-MS compliant browser doesn't support them. In those cases, you can use `getComputedStyle`:

```
function findSize(el, size) {
    /* size must be 'width' or ' height' */
    return window.getComputedStyle
        ? getComputedStyle(el,null).getPropertyValue(size)
        : el['client'+size.substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + size.substr(1)] + 'px';
}
findSize(el, 'width');
findSize(el, 'height');
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/akrjM/88/)

Browser support of `getComputedStyle` and `clientHeight`/`clientWidth` way is at least:

```
                 | IE  | Firefox | Chrome | Safari | Opera
-----------------|-----------------------------------------
getComputedStyle | 9   | <=3     | 1      | <=4    | <=10
client           | <=5 | <=3     | 1      | <=4    | <=10
```

<sup>(`<=n` means that it's supported at least from version `n`, but I couldn't test previous versions)</sup>

Comment: `clientHeight` and `clientWidth` are not part of any w3c specification

Comment: @Andreas I thought that it was included in some w3c spec after being introduced by MS, but I was wrong. Anyway, major browsers support it.

Comment: @Andreas Now I see [`clientWidth`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-cssom-view-20080222/#elementview-clientwidth) and [`clientHeight`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-cssom-view-20080222/#elementview-clientheight) were defined in [CSSOM View Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-cssom-view-20080222/), W3C Working Draft 22 February 2008.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) for this

```
<div style="wdith:50%">50% width</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​

(function() {
    var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];

    console.log(window.getComputedStyle(div, null)["width"]);
}())​
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wMdz5/)

Supported by all major browsers and IE9+. For lower versions of IE have a look at [`currentStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, it's `wdith`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [**This**](http://jsfiddle.net/TfuNC/).

The jQuery key is :

```
$("#div").width();
```

Comment: He doesn't have jQuery tag, so I guess he doesn't use jQuery

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery key is :

```
$("#div").width($("#div").width());
```